# Conditioning general distribution

Tags: probability, measure-theory, reference-request, conditional-probability

Suppose we have two random variables $X, Y: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined in some probability space. I want a formal definition for the conditional distribution of $X$ given a value of the other variable say $Y = y$. We know that when $(X,Y)$ has density $f_{X,Y}$ with marginal distributions $f_X$ and $f_Y$ respectively, we define the conditional density (and so the conditional distribution) motivated by the discrete case as 
$$f_{X|Y=y}(\cdot, y) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(\cdot, y)}{f_Y(y)}$$

To this point I want to make an observation, we construct a probability distribution but not a random variable $X|Y=y$ whose density is $f_{X|Y=y}$.

I have two questions:

**First**

¿What is the formal definition for conditioning, if we dont have a joint density, we know only the law $P_{X,Y}$. I found the following definition without explanation:

$\textit{The conditional distribution}$ $P_{X|Y = y}$ $\textit{is the distribution of} \hspace{0,1cm}$ $\varphi(U,y)$ $\textit{where} \hspace{0,1cm}$ $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ $\textit{is a borel function and}\hspace{0,1cm}$ $U$ $\textit{is chossen independent of}\hspace{0,1cm}$  $Y$ $\textit{and such that}$ $(\varphi(U,Y), Y)$ $\textit{is distributed as}$ $P_{X,Y}$.

Note that the condition $Y = y$ is given by $\varphi(U,y)$ and obiously in independence $U = X$ and $\varphi(x,y) = x$.

**Second**

Suppose now we have a probability distribution $P$ over $X\times Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are arbitrary **sets**. One can talk about conditioning here?.

I will be very grateful if you give me any reference, I am very interested in question number two.

Comment: Indeed your observation is correct: technically/pedantically speaking there are no such things as “conditional random variables” only random variables with conditional distributions, conditional on some event. The formal definition beyond the use of densities is readily available on Wikipedia, in Kolmogorov’s *foundations of theory of probability*, and very concisely in David Williams *Probability with Martingales*, for reference.